# MYSQL NOT IN query using DISTINCT()

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables.  One is a list of predictions (aka PREDS).  The other is a collection of summary statistics about the predictions aka STATS.  So far PREDS has about 1mm lines but it is actually generated by only 30 different models so each model generates ~ 30k predictions.

In the STATS table each row is summary stats for one model.  There are about 100 lines in the STATS table due to old models that are no longer in existence.  I am trying to find which of the models in the PREDS table are NOT in the STATS table so I can update the summary stats for them.

I'm trying stuff like this:

```
SELECT distinct(t1.modelnum) FROM `PREDS` t1
where t1.modelnum not in (select distinct(modelnum) from `STATS` t2);
```

but it takes forever to run.  I can run the separate sides quickly (`select distinct(modelnum) from...`)  but when combined it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an index on PREDS.modelnum?

Comment: By the way, `DISTINCT` is not a function, you know (not in MySQL). It's a clause that makes the statement return distinct *rows*. Yes, it applies to rows, not to columns. (And the column in parentheses is just a column in parentheses.)

Comment: @juergend: you were right, indexes were the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the [`modelnum` column [in *both* tables] can not be NULL, the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the most efficient means](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT p.modelnum
     FROM PREDS p
LEFT JOIN STATS s ON s.modelnum = p.modelnum
    WHERE s.modelnum IS NULL
```

Otherwise, because of duplicates -- the [NOT] EXISTS clause might be a better choice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.modelnum
  FROM PREDS p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM STATS s
                    WHERE s.modelnum = p.modelnum)
```

Here's a [look at how the NOT IN/NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN/IS NULL stack up when columns **are nullable**](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what indexes you have. A `not exits` might help you

```
SELECT 
  distinct(t1.modelnum) 
FROM 
  `PREDS` t1
where NOT EXISTS
  (
      SELECT
        NULL
     FROM
        `STATS` t2
     WHERE
        t2.modelnum=t1.modelnum
  );
```

Then you just have to do the distict one time.